# Strange behavior JSON data

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, json, gtl

In a data extension we receive some basic JSON data. Like this:

```
[
{
    "adressoort": 1,
    "is_ontvangstadres": "true",
    "persoonsnaam": "Test",
    "bedrijfsnaam": null,
    "postcode": "01234AB",
    "straatnaam": "Test",
    "huisnummer": "1",
    "huisnummer_toevoeging": null,
    "woonplaats": "",
    "land": "NL"
}
```

]

Based on this data with some additional data from other fields in the data extension we concat a URL like this:

```
{{#adressenInformatie}}
{{#if adressoort=="1"}} 
%%[ var @landJSON, @postcodeJSON 
set @landJSON = TreatAsContent('{{land}}') 
set @postcodeJSON = TreatAsContent('{{postcode}}') 
set @link_barcodeURL = concat('https://OUR-URL',@barcode,'- 
',@landJSON,'-',@postcodeJSON) 
]%%
<a class="link" href="%%=RedirectTo(@link_barcodeURL)=%%" target="_blank" titel="Btn 
%%=v(@barcode)=%%" alias="BtnStandaardINT" style="color: #3D43E6; text-decoration: 
none;">%%=v(@barcode)=%%</a>
{{/if}} 
{{/adressenInformatie}}
```

The outcome of the URL is this: https://OUR-URL/123456789-NL-1234AB

As you can see the 0 (zero) before the 1234AB has stripped out. Why is that? And how can we fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. The following did the trick:

```
set @formattedField = TreatAsContent('{{=Concat([XXXXXX])}}')
```